# Creating RANK in Excel with conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rank

I have a file I need to have ranked but need to ignore specified rows.

Here is an example.

```
   A          B          C
INCLUDE     ORDER     RANK ORDER
  1           1           1
  0           2           
  0           6           
  1           7           7
  1           3           3
  0           5            
  1           4           4
```

I need to ignore blank spaces and start ranking from when the 1 appears in column A. The values start on Row 2.

Desired table:

```
   A           B              C
INCLUDE      ORDER        RANK ORDER
   1           1              1
   0           2               
   0           6       
   1           7              4
   1           3              2
   0           5             
   1           4              3
```

I have done `=IF(A2 = 1,IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,1,B$2:B2,) > RANK.EQ(B2,B$2:B2,0),RANK.EQ(B2,$B$2:$B$300,1)), " ")` This will get the first table but I need the second table any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this seems to work:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=IFNA(XMATCH(B2:B8,SORT(FILTER(B2:B8,A2:A8))),"")
```

Comment: Getting Spill Error

Comment: @Coding_Nubie, just apply the formula once in `C2`, make sure the cells below all the way to `C8` are clear. A spill error occurs because you are in one way or another using the cells below `C2`.

Comment: I checked columns, all in number format. So I am confused in the spill error.

Comment: The format can be fine, its just that the formula in `C2` wants to spill (auto-write) the results down into `C3:C8` however, you have either dragged the formula down or you have got other values in that range that is blocking this behaviour, hence the error-type. It has nothing to do with formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=IFNA(XMATCH(B2:B8,TOCOL(SORT(IFS(A2:A8,B2:B8)),3)),"")
```

---

Comment: Getting SPILL error

Comment: How come, I am not getting any error, check whether you have anything in between the cells in the column C, because the above formula will spill.

Comment: I am checking if there is numbers not formatted correctly, could decimals give this issue I see that I do have a few in my column B.

Comment: Are you sure about the decimals ? Still it wont be giving a spill error.

Comment: I checked all columns I am using number format for column A and B. I am not sure why I am getting spill error at this point.

Comment: @Coding_Nubie can you post a screencap, to let us see. With the exact post of your data. Also are you using a structured references that is a table? then it wont work. Because dynamic array formulas are not supported for those structured reference

Comment: Can't screencap off this machine it has restrictions but I saw the error and works now thank you.

Comment: @Coding_Nubie glad to know it worked out

Answer (score 0):

I found a VERY Simple formula to address this:
https://exceljet.net/formulas/rank-if-formula

=COUNTIFS($V8:$V1958 << Criteria Range ( Obviously infinite, since this is COUNTIFS )>>,V9<< Criteria1 >>,$AJ$8:$AJ$1958 << Values Range >>,"<="&AJ9<< Current Row >>)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).